# how to connect two different lans

Tags: local-area-network, bridge, router

I have in my office two different LANS with two different ISP. Lan A is faster than Lan B.

We want to share files and printers and everything as if it was only one LAN, the thing is that we don't want to share the fast ISP.

I have a linksys DD-WRT, I don't know if I could use it, an old dude here told me that I might need a bridge.

We have a small office (only 15 employees), and I'm a developer but don't know much about networking.

Comment: Hire a contractor or consultant who **does** know something about networking, then.

Comment: Purchase a Dual-Link (aka dual-wan, multi-wan, multi-isp) router.  Connect that to your two ISP routers.  Put everything behind the Dual-Link router.  Done.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Some small businesses might have a low budget for IT. Not everyone can afford a dedicated consultant for office networking. This question fits SF's scope in my opinion.

Comment: @Lukas  Well, you're free to answer it, but I would say 1) any business that can't afford a few hundred bucks to have a consultant in for the less than a day this would take can't afford an office network either and 2) a developer trying to figure out how to hook up a SOHO router to two ISPs is ***not*** an [`Information Technology Professional`, as the site scope is, according to the FAQ.](http://serverfault.com/faq)  I don't care a whole lot either way, mind you, but according to the plain language of our FAQ, this question is not topical for ServerFault.

Comment: @HopelessN00b you are a genius then, you could answer that to every question here don't you think?

Comment: @Zoredache thanks dude!! turns out a friend have one, he's gonna sell it to me at cheap price, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

File sharing will work cross-subnet. I'd suggest something like the following:

- You have 2 routers. 1 connected to each WAN.
- Router 1 has the IP range 192.168.1.* and router 2 192.168.2.*
- One of the extra LAN interfaces on router 1 is assigned an IP address within the 192.168.2.* range. Let's say 192.168.2.100.
- Router 2 has a static route added to it to direct all traffic for 192.168.1.* via 192.168.2.100.
- Router 1 will inherently route traffic to the other subnet as it's directly connected

You'll lose the ability to use some broadcast protocols like NetBios but can mount file and print shares using the IP address.

Router 1 will likely be more expensive than a standard home router to support multiple LAN interfaces. Most cheap routers will support static routes and act as router 2.

As was pointed out before, this can be done with a single router that supports multi-WAN.

Comment: in your step 3, when you say one of the extra lan interfaces, You mean another ethernet port right ?  also when you say Router 1 will likely be more expensive than a standard home router to support multiple LAN interfaces.  I feel like LAN interface is a different thing than LAN ports is it ?